# Indexing on object fields within an array that can potentially hold unlimited number of objects in mongodb

Tags: index, mongodb

In our app, we use mongo to store data for reporting on large number of documents.
Here is an example of one of the documents that we currently store in mongo:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("58b72edc2e0efb6dfcfe3a02"),
  "version": 5,
  "checklistId": "lQj2y_6CLOXXb3-JyIxFXw",
  "templateRevisionId": "oaCphmLt07O_jak5TWJHrw",
  "templateId": "ld0Vy_3d4JwMWHVc6QpCbw",
  "columns": [
    {
      "kind": "Checklist",
      "descriptor": "Name",
      "data": "Blank Checklist - Mon Jul 6 at 12:00PM",
      "normalized_data": "blank checklist - mon jul 6 at 12:00pm"
    },
    {
      "kind": "Checklist",
      "descriptor": "CreatedDate",
      "data": NumberLong(1436194800000)
    },
    {
      "kind": "Checklist",
      "descriptor": "UpdatedDate",
      "data": NumberLong(1436194800000)
    },
    {
      "kind": "Checklist",
      "descriptor": "Status",
      "data": "Active",
      "normalized_data": "active"
    },
    {
      "kind": "Checklist",
      "descriptor": "TotalTasks",
      "data": 3
    },
    {
      "kind": "Checklist",
      "descriptor": "TasksCompleted",
      "data": 0
    },
    {
      "kind": "Checklist",
      "descriptor": "DueDate",
      "data": null
    },
    {
      "kind": "Task",
      "data": "NotCompleted",
      "descriptor": "Status",
      "groupId": "h64R0Grzb4gamgx18AZOCg",
      "normalized_data": "notcompleted"
    },
    {
      "kind": "Task",
      "descriptor": "UpdatedDate",
      "groupId": "h64R0Grzb4gamgx18AZOCg",
      "data": NumberLong(1436194800000)
    },
    {
      "kind": "Task",
      "descriptor": "Assignees",
      "groupId": "h64R0Grzb4gamgx18AZOCg",
      "data": [

      ]
    },
    {
      "kind": "Task",
      "descriptor": "DueDate",
      "groupId": "h64R0Grzb4gamgx18AZOCg",
      "data": null
    },
    {
      "kind": "Task",
      "data": "NotCompleted",
      "descriptor": "Status",
      "groupId": "oZnhF1SawbaqCOl9xhdGkw",
      "normalized_data": "notcompleted"
    },
    {
      "kind": "Task",
      "descriptor": "UpdatedDate",
      "groupId": "oZnhF1SawbaqCOl9xhdGkw",
      "data": NumberLong(1436194800000)
    },
    {
      "kind": "Task",
      "descriptor": "Assignees",
      "groupId": "oZnhF1SawbaqCOl9xhdGkw",
      "data": [

      ]
    },
    {
      "kind": "Task",
      "descriptor": "DueDate",
      "groupId": "oZnhF1SawbaqCOl9xhdGkw",
      "data": null
    },
    {
      "kind": "Task",
      "data": "NotCompleted",
      "descriptor": "Status",
      "groupId": "kAaghTaEeNhc7eFkPY5Bmw",
      "normalized_data": "notcompleted"
    },
    {
      "kind": "Task",
      "descriptor": "UpdatedDate",
      "groupId": "kAaghTaEeNhc7eFkPY5Bmw",
      "data": NumberLong(1436194800000)
    },
    {
      "kind": "Task",
      "descriptor": "Assignees",
      "groupId": "kAaghTaEeNhc7eFkPY5Bmw",
      "data": [

      ]
    },
    {
      "kind": "Task",
      "descriptor": "DueDate",
      "groupId": "kAaghTaEeNhc7eFkPY5Bmw",
      "data": null
    }
  ],
  "organizationId": "lW5Eor_PX3XApaPVTHVEiQ",
  "checklistRevisionId": "pMk7J1-TwrXEMwW_4t9Bcg",
  "updatedDate": NumberLong(1488400092097),
  "createdDate": NumberLong(1488400092097)
}
```

In general, there is no limit on number of docs that we need to generate a report on. Also, every document, may potentially have different number of columns in it.

One of the simplest reports that we run is something like this:

```
collection.find({ templateId: 'ld0Vy_3d4JwMWHVc6QpCbw' }).sort({ 'columns.1.data': -1 })
```

However, if the filtered collection is big enough, mongo runs out of memory:

```
Error: error: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "Executor error during find command: OperationFailed: Sort operation used more than the maximum 33554432 bytes of RAM. Add an index, or specify a smaller limit.",
    "code" : 96,
    "codeName" : "OperationFailed"
}
```

As suggested, I added an index to this particular data field in column (1), and in fact it id did help. But that is just one usecase.
Since the report is built dynamically, the filter and the column we need to sort by, can and need to vary. 
Note: even if we paginate through results, without the index, we still get the same memory problem.

The question is, what is the right way to organize indexes in this situation?
OR
Maybe, we see the restructure the data completely?

Note: even if we paginate through results, without the index, we still get the same memory problem.

Comment: That is how NoSQL works. You get the key + 1 sort column per collection. If you need to sort by another field, the query basically has to retrieve all documents and sort them in memory. MongoDB has a hard limit of 32MB for this sorting. You have to create indexes if you have bigger tables, or create a new collection (e.g. with templateid+date+ref to document, or, harder to maintain but possible if the data doesn't change/just gets extended, a copy of your data) - which will basically act as an index anyway, so you might as well simply create an index (which can be sparse)

Comment: This comment is simply inaccurate for any noSQL system that allows compound secondary indexes.

Comment: for the OP, I would suggest two possible paths.  1) use aggregation with allowDiskUse:true option instead of using "find" as aggregation can sort with spilling to disk and therefore won't have any size of sorted result upper limit.  2) For performance reasons, you may find that a different indexing strategy is required.   It's certainly *not* a good idea to either query or index/sort based on position in the array - why not use the actual field to sort by?

Comment: Do you always filter by templateId only?  And do you always want to return the full document (i.e. you will need all the columns for this query? or only the ones that match some other condition?)

Comment: @AsyaKamsky Eventually, we will need to be able to search by any of these.

Comment: The it's not a database you need, it's a search engine.